# How to copy any pdf data created using xsl fo

Tags: xml, xslt

I have generated pdf file using xsl and xml. This file is complete and correct but for some reason I am not able to copy any content from that pdf into clipboard.
New requirement wants some of texts available on the pdf to copy and paste it in some other application.

Is there is any configuration on **xsl** level or maybe at that specific **node** level that I have do so that generated pdf's text will get copy easily into clipboard and one can paste it into any other application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which XSL Formatter are you using?

Comment: are you asking formatter tool to create xsl ? if yes then no I have not used any, used only eclipse editor nothing else..

Comment: Sorry, which XSL-FO formatter to produce PDF?